# Bootstrap Carousel stops working after first switch on IE

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Bootstrap 2.0.2 Carousel does not work on IE (7~10).

I set it to cycle at the very start. **It will switch item for the first time**, and then stop working all together. Sending calls using the browser console such as `$('.carousel').carousel(12)` will simply return the carousel container object.

I have added the class 'slide' but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by [a few bugs](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2945) of bootstrap. Upgrading it probably fixes the issue. I took the route of modifying my carousel code:

```
  ...
  if (!$.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')) {
    this.$element.trigger('slide')
  ...
```

to:

```
  ...
  if($.browser.msie){
    this.$element.trigger('slide')
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, I was on bootstrap 2.0.3, but could not afford to upgrade. If you see at the top of bootstrap.js file there is a portion called bootstrap-transition.js.

Update:

```
transEndEventNames = {
           'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd'
        ,  'MozTransition'    : 'transitionend'
        ,  'OTransition'      : 'oTransitionEnd'
        ,  'msTransition'     : 'MSTransitionEnd'
        ,  'transition'       : 'transitionend'
        }
```

To:

```
transEndEventNames = {
           'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd'
        ,  'MozTransition'    : 'transitionend'
        ,  'OTransition'      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend'
        ,  'transition'       : 'transitionend'
        }
```

This fixed it for me.